# Tokens for Profile 2 field

Tags: users

I created a field for users using the [Profile 2 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) with machine name "field_user_country"

I created a block on my user profile page and i need to dynamically display the country of the currently viewed profile.

I have tried various tokens and they do not work.

What token can I use to get the country of the currently viewed user profile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue at the moment. Looking into including a few fields from a Profile2 content type into a Display Suite custom code field.

I used the following PHP code in the custom code field (using php filter format and enabling tokens, just in case). Then I was able to view a collapsed tree of all tokens available to that node.

You could prabably do the same in a block and have it displayed when you need it.

```
<?php
$output .= 'Available tokens:';
$output .= theme('token_tree', array('node'), TRUE, TRUE);
return $output;
?>
```

I'm sure there's a better way, but that quickly worked for me! gOOD LUCK.